# Como agregar una array a una collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo este esta `collection` obtenida desde la base de datos y deseo agregar un nuevo arreglo y que éste tome la posición `0` con esta estructura:

```
0 => {#322 ▼
      +"idcategoria": nuevo valor
      +"nombre": "nuevo valor "
      +"descripcion": nuevo valor
      +"condicion": "nuevo valor "
    }

Collection {#306 ▼
  #items: array:12 [▼
    0 => {#322 ▼
      +"idcategoria": 1
      +"nombre": "Memorias"
      +"descripcion": null
      +"condicion": "Activo"
    }
    1 => {#318 ▼
      +"idcategoria": 2
      +"nombre": "Audio"
      +"descripcion": null
      +"condicion": "Activo"
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres agregar ese registro o modificarlo? Tal y como lo tienes redactado parece que quieres modificar el registro del índice 0. ¿Podrías decirme con qué propósito quieres hacerlo o qué esperas como resultado? No me queda claro con los datos y la captura de pantalla proporcionada.

Comment: quisiera agregar uno nuevo en la posición 0  "0 => {#322 ▼
      +"idcategoria": nuevo valor
      +"nombre": "nuevo valor "
      +"descripcion": nuevo valor
      +"condicion": "nuevo valor "
    }"

Comment: ¿Aplicando los cambios en la base de datos o sólo en la colección con la que trabajas? ¿Los datos son instancia de una clase o es un array asociativo normal?

Comment: solo en la colección en la que trabajo,

Answer (score 6):

Para agregar un elemento a la colección y que tome la primera «posición», utiliza el método prepend():

```
$collection->prepend([
    "idcategoria" => 10,
    "nombre" => "bla",
    "descripcion" => "...",
    "condicion" => "nuevo"
]);
```

Más información en https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-prepend

Comment: +1 Me fui por la edición de un elemento sin pensar antes que se podría referir a simplemente agregarlo al principio x)